# how to using IN operator in ssrs expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

First of all sorry about my english. 
I want to use in ssrs  in tablix-fields expresion something like this:

```
=iif(CStr(Fields!Id.Value) in Split(Parameters!IdListStr.Value, ","), Fields!Sum, "")
```

where Parameters!IdListStr.Value = "1,2,3".

is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the filter on the dataset using the below values,

```
 Expression := Fields!Id.Value
 Operator := In
 Value:= Split(Parameters!IdListStr.Value, ",")
```

And if you dont want to filter out the records from the dataset then you an use the below expression

```
= IIF(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!IdListStr.Value, Fields!Id.Value) > -1,Fields!Sum.Value,Nothing)
```

Comment: I thought about it,  but what if the id 1 is a substring of id 11,  may be use InStr(Parameters!IdListStr.Value.ToString(),"," & Cstr(Fields!Id.Value) & ","), but what if the id is first?

Comment: Ok there is another way to do it, You can apply the filter on the dataset. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Array.IndexOf  help

Comment: I also want to ask, what .net  function i can use in ssrs ? Сan i use all function from System namespace.?

Comment: Yes you can use all core function from system namespace