# SSRS Reporting Syntax

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Using the following filter for a SSRS report.

**Expression:**

*=If((Parameters!GroupA.Value() In Fields!Related_GroupA.Value) Or (Parameters!GroupB.Value() In Fields!Related_GroupB.Value) Or (Parameters!GroupA.Value() In Fields!GroupA.Value) Or (Parameters!GroupB.Value() In Fields!GroupB.Value))*

**Operator:**

*=*

**Value:**

*True*

Believe the syntax for the "If statement" and use of "in" and "Or" may be incorrect. Need to return the results if the value selected in the report parameter, appears in one of two places. (e.g. if Parameters!GroupA is in Fields!Related_GroupA or in Fields!GroupA)

**Current Error:**

*'If' operator requires either two or three operands.*

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Edited post to show error. Report not running currently.

Answer (score 0):

> 'If' operator requires either two or three operands.

You have the "if" part in your statement but you don't specify what to do if it returns true or false. Also, use "iif" instead of "if."

```
=iif(
(Parameters!GroupA.Value In Fields!Related_GroupA.Value) Or 
(Parameters!GroupB.Value In Fields!Related_GroupB.Value) Or 
(Parameters!GroupA.Value In Fields!GroupA.Value) Or 
(Parameters!GroupB.Value In Fields!GroupB.Value), <Value if true>, <Value if false>)
```

If you only want to return true or false then you don't need to use the iif operator because the "=" operator returns a boolean value (True/False).

If this is the case then you can simply use:

```
=(Parameters!GroupA.Value = Fields!Related_GroupA.Value) Or 
 (Parameters!GroupB.Value = Fields!Related_GroupB.Value) Or 
 (Parameters!GroupA.Value = Fields!GroupA.Value) Or 
 (Parameters!GroupB.Value = Fields!GroupB.Value)
```

Note that I changed "In" to "=" because there isn't an IN operator you can use in the ssrs expressions but there are a few workarounds. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432312/how-to-using-in-operator-in-ssrs-expression) and [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/768876/SSRS-filters-using-IN).